# Image not showing up when using .html in JQuery

Tags: jquery, image

I try to add an image on an AJAX request on my website, but for some reason, the images doesn't show up. Although, the generated HTML is correct.

This is my code:

```
$('.field-name-field-testimony-photo').wrap('<div class="picture-preview-container" />');
$('<div class="picture-preview" />').insertAfter('.picture-preview-container');

$('.form-item input.form-file', context).change(function() {
    $parent = $(this).closest('.form-item');
    $('.picture-preview').html('<img src="https://www.google.be/path-to-my-image.jpg" />');
});
```

And the generated HTML is correct as far as I can see...

```
<div class="picture-preview">
    <img src="https://www.google.be/path-to-my-image.jpg" />
</div>
```

Did I forget something in my code to make sure this images appears?

Comment: Sorry, a typo... I did use the src

Comment: If your generated HTML is correct, the problem is somewhere else. Maybe the `picture-preview` div, or the image, is not visible for some CSS-related reason?

Comment: after changing it to src , do u still have the prob ??

Comment: Did you open the console and check if the image returns a 404 ?

Comment: Did you confirm (browser's dev tools) that the img tag is actually added to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

As Salman has said above
take a look at

```
<img scr="https://www.google.be/path-to-my-image.jpg" />
```

in your last line

and convert scr ===> src

```
<img src="https://www.google.be/path-to-my-image.jpg" />
```

Comment: he wrote it by mistake he did the right thing in implementation.

Comment: why the downvote , i have said the right thing before he edited , even i asked him as well

Comment: can i please be told the reason for downvote , i answered when the syntax was wrong , so wat about it ??

Comment: @Juhana : when i answered , this was one of the prob, possibly the ans , anyways i wanna be more careful from now on